# Why do parts of a Spam Email disappear, when I move the email from the Junk Folder to any other Folder; including the Inbox folder?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, spam-prevention, email-client, hotmail

I have received a Sextortion/Extortion email, via my Hotmail Account, which landed in my Junk Folder. The email basically claimed that they had accessed my computer where they had obtained vulnerable images of me as well as having been watching me via my WebCam and would release compromising clips of my activities if I did not immediately transfer funds via Bitcoin.

Needless to say, their back story was completely fabricated and designed to invoke fear to get people to transfer funds without thinking it through.

Whilst their email was littered with grammatical errors and broken English, as well as a series of nonsensical words, it did contain a username and password that I used to use.  After thinking it through, and checking out the email, it appears that their email contained scripting language that was simply injecting the contents of a breached database from 2012.

Whilst checking out the email, I noticed that the content generated by the scripting language is visible when the email resides within the Junk Folder but as soon as I move the email to another Folder, including the Inbox, this generated content disappears.

Similarly, the content does not appear when accessing the email via my phone; even when the email resides within the Junk Folder.

Is anyone able to explain why this may be the case?

Comment: I’m not sure what do you mean by “content generated by the scripting language”. Normally, messages in the Junk E-mail folder is converted to Plain Text. If we move the message out of the Junk E-mail folder, it will be automatically converted to HTML.

Comment: @Perry:  The email contained several paragraphs that contained nonsensical information as well as an old username and password, repeated.  It was these parts of the email that would not be visible on mobile devices or when the email was removed from the Junk Folder.  As such, I assumed it was some kind of scripting language.  Maybe JavaScript.  I can understand how that could have resulted in the content not being visible on mobile devices but not sure why the content would disappear when moving the email away from the Junk Folder.

Comment: I did some research but haven't found related information. You may try checking the email on the web mail. By the way, could I know why you want to see the scripting content in Inbox?

Comment: (1/2) @Perry:  Thanks for taking the time to research the matter.  Just logged into the webmail, where the content that appears in the Junk Folder (When accessing the email via Outlook Client) does not appear at all; regardless of whether the email resides in the Junk Folder or Inbox.  How could this be, where the content could be missing in the webmail (outlook.live.com) but appears when the Junk Folder is accessed via Outlook Client?

Comment: (2/2)  As for wanting to see the scripting content in the Inbox, it was a matter of curiosity as I was looking to understand why content would appear when the email was in the Junk Folder but not elsewhere.  Could it be that when emails are in the Junk Folder, there is still some kind of 'link' between the sender and recipient, whereby they could change such content their end and it would differ my end but if the email was moved away from the Junk Folder, that 'connection' would be broke.  Therefore, explaining why part of the content would then not be visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Content will seem to “change” in MIME multipart emails like this since there are literally separate email parts for HTML and plain text content.

I am not as familiar with the way Microsoft Outlook works nowadays since I don’t use Outlook anymore and when I did it was in macOS. But when you say this:

> “Whilst checking out the email, I noticed that the content generated by the scripting language is visible when the email resides within the Junk Folder but as soon as I move the email to another Folder, including the Inbox, this generated content disappears.”

And then [this comment by Perry](https://superuser.com/questions/1445841/why-do-parts-of-a-spam-email-disappear-when-i-move-the-email-from-the-junk-fold#comment2181580_1445841) explains things on a more specific technical level:

> “I’m not sure what do you mean by “content generated by the scripting language”. Normally, messages in the Junk E-mail folder is converted to Plain Text. If we move the message out of the Junk E-mail folder, it will be automatically converted to HTML.”

That explains it to me. Unless of course modern Microsoft Outlook actually modifies “Junk” email as a preventative security measure of some sort; but I doubt it. Explanation below.

Emails that have HTML in one view and a text view in another are called MIME multipart emails. The goal of multipart emails is to customize content based on web browser capabilities. More information can be [found here on this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/tylermakin/d820f65eb3c9dd98d58721c7fb1939a8).

So the reason you see some content in one view and others in another is because the MIME multipart content for `Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"` is different than the content for `Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"`.

Note one is `text/html` and the other is `text/plain`? In normal and legitimate emails, the sender would (perhaps) have some fancy HTML content for the `text/html` portion and then a cleanly formatted version of pure text for the `text/plain` version. Why do this? Easy: Viewing HTML as plain text would expose all of the un-rendered HTML content contained in the message which is messy and hard to read. Thus a plain text version is included so things look nice for those who wish to view text only emails.

In this case, a malicious actor might have the core SPAM stuff in the HTML part of the MIME multipart email and the plain text version could be random stuff for maybe a plain text only version of the content of the SPAM stuff.

If you wish to view the whole/raw message then just view the message (regardless of the folder) as RAW source or whatever option you have to view the message as a plain-text file. Heck, you could probably just save the full message source to a text file and read it that way.

But fair warning: You might not learn anything from such an exercise. SPAM emails like this just attempt to lure you to a hacker website and that is where the “party” happens.

So if you are curious, go for it… It should be safe to view the raw message source. But don’t expect to learn much.